# Swift.- UIAppereance of UISwitch does not take layer.cornerRadius into account

Tags: swift, uikit, uiswitch, uiappearance

I am trying to use `appearance` to set general default layouts/designs across the app. For `UISwitch`, to set the `off` color not only at the border, one has to do a tweak (see [Change color of UISwitch in "off" state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10348869/change-color-of-uiswitch-in-off-state)):

```
uiswitch.backgroundColor = .red
uiswitch.layer.cornerRadius = 16
```

Whenever I do:

```
let toggle = UISwitch()
toggle.tintColor = offColor // see "global vars and methods below"
toggle.onTintColor = onColor
toggle.backgroundColor = offColor
toggle.layer.cornerRadius = 16
view.addSubview(toggle)
constraintToCenter(toggle: toggle)
```

It works and I get:

[image: UISwitch with off color]

But if I use the `appearance` like this:

```
let toggle = UISwitch()
view.addSubview(toggle)
constraintToCenter(toggle: toggle)
UISwitch.newSetUpDefaultAppearance(onColor: onColor, offColor: offColor)

public extension UISwitch {
    class func newSetUpDefaultAppearance(onColor: UIColor, offColor: UIColor) {
        let defaultAppereance = appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [])
        defaultAppereance.onTintColor = onColor
        defaultAppereance.backgroundColor = offColor
        defaultAppereance.tintColor = offColor
        defaultAppereance.layer.cornerRadius = 16.0
        print (defaultAppereance.layer.cornerRadius) // prints 0.0
    }
}
```

I get:

### [image]

Global vars and methods:

```
let onColor = UIColor.black
let offColor = UIColor.gray

func constraintToCenter(view: UIView) {
    toggle.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false        
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([toggle.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor), toggle.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)])
}
```

---

Does someone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Appearance Proxies & Layers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8778696/appearance-proxies-layers), it looks like it is not possible because `CALayer` does not conform to `UIAppearance` and does not have an `appearance` method.

The only way to do it is the answer by Sandy Chapman in that answer. Here is how it looks in Swift and it works:

```
public class Switch: UISwitch {
    // dynamic is needed for UIAppearance support
    @objc dynamic var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        }
    }

    public class func globalDefaultAppearance() {
        let defaultAppereance = appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [])
        defaultAppereance.onTintColor = .red
        defaultAppereance.backgroundColor = .yellow
        defaultAppereance.tintColor = .red
        defaultAppereance.cornerRadius = 16.0
    }
}
```

Using

```
let toggle = Switch()
UISwitch.globalSetUpDefaultAppearance()
```

works perfectly.